# Cross-site AJAX using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-site

I have an existing jQuery plugin which makes a lot of AJAX calls (mostly JSON). I am wondering what is the quickest to allow it to do cross-site calls i.e. the $.get and $.post URL's will not be from the same domain.

I have heard of JSONP, but was wondering if someone could give me an concrete example to go about the whole process. I want to make minimal changes if possible to my script. Should I use a proxy.php of sorts?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSONP will allow you to do cross-site calls. [See jQuery docs on that matter.](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax)

The concept is simple: instead of doing a normal Ajax call, jQuery will append a `<script>` tag to your `<head>`. In order for this to work, your JSON data needs to be wrapped in a
function call.

Your server needs to send information in such way (PHP example):

```
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $_GET['jsonp_callback'] . '(' . $json . ');';
```

Then, you can use jQuery to fetch that information:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: 'http://myotherserver.com/getdata',
  success: function () {
    // do stuff
  },
});
```

More information is available here: [What is JSONP?](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)

Comment: Nice! I'll go ahead and test this. Except that i think the echo statment should print the $json variable, and not the $data. Is that correct ?

Comment: @PHP_Jedi: That would be correct. I've just corrected that typo (which, embarrassingly, has been there for 2 years).

Comment: Be aware that JSONP opens up your server to any website. If the data in use is public like google maps, it's fine, but if the data is something the user uses logged-in, JSONP offers no cross-origin protection and HTTP_REFERER won't help you (because Flash can be used to spoof REFERER). It's easy to craft a malicious page that steals the user's data or modifies their account. Use something that allows you to control origin like flxhr if the data is sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the remote domain or the remote domain has a permissive [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) you can drop in a library like [flXHR](http://flxhr.flensed.com/) in conjunction with its [jQuery plugin](http://flxhr.flensed.com/jquery.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CORS instead of JSONP, works with ff,chrome,safari.
CORS is less troublesome to setup and requires only a filter in server-side.

Please go through this article.Well explained and similar.
Only constraint is IE does not support this and older versions of FF,chrome also has some issues.

http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Comment: Can you describe how to use it in your answer, please?