# Consuming JSON with JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, web-services, json, jsonp

2 short questions. I would appreciate an answer or a pointer to an answered question on SO (I searched before asking :)).

1. I'd like to consume one of the [TRYNT](http://www.trynt.com/)'s web services that returns a JSON object (like [this one](http://www.trynt.com/symbol-lookup-api/v2/?s=IBM&fo=json&f=0) for example). Am I right in deducing that if they don't specify JSONP, there is no way I can consume those services from the client side, without a server-side proxy - due to cross-site scripting limitations?
2. Ok, so I tried implementing a PHP proxy to consume the service and return the JSON to HTML, but found out my (free) web hosting service blocks the CURL libarary. Being a newbie PHP developer (ASP.Net is my usual expertise, but I decided it's time to branch out :) ) - what other options do I have to get the JSON results from PHP?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.trynt.com/symbol-lookup-api/v2/?s=IBM&fo=json&f=0';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Depends on your server configuration of course. Worth a shot!

Comment: Yeah, provided file_get_contents is allowed to open urls (fopen_url I think it is in php.ini), this oughta work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but stream_get_contents is in the 'disable_functions' list (along with allow_url_fopen, curl and along long list of similar functions) - in short, it looks like I'm screwed :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Please read [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197802/cross-site-ajax-using-jquery).
2. If CURL is blocked, probably other methods for getting remote content is also blocked. If `allow_url_fopen` is set to true on php.ini, you can use a function like [fopen](http://php.net/fopen). Also, you can try [opening a socket](http://php.net/fsockopen) to the server.

Comment: @Nathan:
1. Only helpful if you control the service side as well - which I don't :(
2. allow_url_fopen is blocked in PHP.ini. Guess my provider really doesn't want me to consume anything :(

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy, most free providers block it just for you have to buy a professional plan. :P (#Capitalism)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flash movie (hidden, if needed, with dimensions 0,0), with flash's crossdomain.xml to proxy between the remote server and javascript.

more information on the technique: http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000294.html