# Post JSON data cross site using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-site AJAX using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197802/cross-site-ajax-using-jquery)

I am trying to post json to a different site to render an image:

jdata holds my JSON data and all this is done under a click event.

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: jdata,
    url: 'the site url',
    success: function() {
        alert('hi');
    }

});
```

EDIT: sorry for not posting the problem... I can't seem to post the data to a different site. Is my syntax correct?  I looked at the other cross site post here on stack overflow, but I keep posting to "http://siteiAmOn.com/siteIWanttoGoto"

Comment: And the problem is ? If you don't tell us if there is a problem *(and what it is)*, we cannot guess ;-)

Comment: you can't do post like that with JSONP.  JSONP uses GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:

> I keep posting to
>   "http://siteiAmOn.com/siteIWanttoGoto"

It sounds like you didn't add "http://" to `'the site url'`. Add that and see if it helps.

Also, is it intentional here that `jdata` is a variable: `jsonp: jdata`?

Comment: i did add http:// in front of it.  jdata is a variable that holds the json that i want to post

Comment: @yookd: The `jsonp` setting is for telling the other server what callback function name to use. It is not for sending data. If you want to send data, you would use `data` not `jsonp`. Also, as @kjy112 said above, JSONP requests use GET not POST, so that could also be causing problems. Perhaps you should do some more [reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) about JSONP.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.  I'll take a deeper look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post the json to another site due to Cross site restrictions. You may have to use scripttag proxy (allows only GET method). Another way is to write a simple server side proxy that will proxy your client side request to the other site. Look for "Cross Domain Javascript issues".