# jquery & go : how do you set a json header

Tags: jquery, go

How do you set a json header in query. I need it to be a string on the server?:

```
...
$.ajax({
  url: '',
  headers: {
    "listkey":{"key1":"val1", "key2": "val2", "key3":"val3"}
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
...
```

Comment: Maybe check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754767/cannot-set-content-type-to-application-json-in-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a simple as adding:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

as an object property. See the `contentType` property in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

**Full Example:**

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      "listkey":{"key1":"val1", "key2": "val2", "key3":"val3"}
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `contentType` property to set the `content-type` header, i.e. what you are sending to the server.

And you can use the `accept` property to tell the server what you would like back.

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  accept: 'application/json',
  url: '',
  headers: {
    "listkey":{"key1":"val1", "key2": "val2", "key3":"val3"}
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  accept: 'application/json',
  url: '',
  headers: {
    "listkey": '{"key1":"val1", "key2": "val2", "key3":"val3"}'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
...
```