# Jquery Ajax post method giving null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i am learning Jquery Ajax method. i try to post one json string , it working using $.post method but not working in $.Ajax method . it is giving 500 error.please give some suggession

---- $.post--- method // working

```
   $.post("About.aspx?type=Test", { 'Data': '[{"Key":"454","Value":["1","3"]},{"Key":"496","Value":["1","2","3"]}]' }, function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            });
   ----c#-----
    public void add()
    {
        string value = Request.Form["Data"];
    }
```

------$.Ajax post--------- method // Not working. but 
if i am passing data as "{'data':'1'}"--working

```
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Contact.aspx/add",
                dataType: "json",
                data:  "{'Data': '[{'Key':'454','Value':['1','3']},{'Key':'496','Value':['1','2','3']}]'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {

                },

                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.status);
                }
            });
  -----c#----
   [WebMethod]
    public static void add( string Data)
    {
    }
```

Comment: the `data` value in your `$.ajax` request is not JSON, it's just a string. and why are you trying to escape all the double quotes  with a backslash?

Comment: dont escape the `data`, just enclose the entire data with single quotes `'`

Comment: @dreamweiver single quotes or double quotes don't matter in javascript/json. and no - he should NOT enclose the entire data with quotes at all, because then it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

**update:**

I maybe misunderstood what you wanted - so if you really want to send the json to the server ***as a string***, then your `data` should look like this:

```
data: {
    roleList : JSON.stringify([{"Key":"454","Value":["1","3"]},{"Key":"496","Value":["1","2","3"]}])
},
```

seems like you want `roleList` as your POST-variable name;
and it's so much easier to use the build-in function `JSON.stringify()` here. nearly every browser got it nowadays.

**additional info about the contentType:**
the `contentType` is giving me weird issues. seems like you are better off not using it at all since you should be fine with the default setting. see this question for further information: [Cannot set content-type to 'application/json' in jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754767/cannot-set-content-type-to-application-json-in-jquery-ajax)

**original answer:**
the `JSON` you had as your `data` value was not valid `JSON` but just a string. plus the `contentType` was invalid. you are fine with not setting the `contentType` at all and just using the default setting:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Contact.aspx/add",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {roleList:[{"Key":"454","Value":["1","3"]},{"Key":"496","Value":["1","2","3"]}]},
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },

    error: function (msg) {
        console.log("error: ", msg.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: if i don't specify the content type ,it is not hitting the web method. string parameter is in the method . so i convert javascript object to string using JSON.stringify method and passing . if i passed just one data like "{'data' :'1'}" is working . but this is not working

Comment: @nichu09 please see my updated answer. try my JSON.stringify version and tell me if it works for you (for me it does - but i got PHP on the server side)

Comment: JSON.stringify using convert javascript object to string. that ouput i passed as string . if i passed as javascript object , you can't able to see the value. so i did this line of code before and pass the value.but using content type  {'data' :'1'}" is working. so why not this one . help appreciated