# Getting "Method not allowed" error after handling a POST request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem like the topic says. I'm new with that stuff and I don't even know where to look for that issue. That's my post method:

```
public class Point
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Point point)
{
    // do stuff
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

and that's my ajax request:

```
var x = $('#input1').val();
var y = $('#input2').val();

$("#btnUpload").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/images",
        data: { x: x, y: y },
        success: function (result) { alert(result) },
        error: function (err) { alert(err.statusText) }
    });
});
```

Did I forget about something?

EDIT: My controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/images")]
public class ImagesController : ApiController
{
    private Bitmap CreateBoard()
    {
        // some stuff I need
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Point point)
    {
        // do stuff
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<int> Get()
    {
        // do other stuff
    }

    [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        // do other other stuff
    }
}
```

GET is working fine.

Comment: you don't have anything inheriting from a `Controller`.

Comment: What controller is your `Post` method in?  What is the route?

Comment: @maccettura edited

Comment: You need to add `[Route("")]` to your POST method too.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Now no matter what I type in input text boxes I get two nulls in Point parameter

Comment: Well, that's a new issue: add `contentType: 'application/json'` to your `$.ajax` object. You may also need to use `JSON.stringify` on the `data` object but I'm not sure - I don't do much jQuery myself. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9758335/2630078).

Comment: I just noticed that you get the values of `#input1` and `#input2` *outside* of the `click` handler, which means the values of `x` and `y` might not be up-to-date when clicking the button.

Comment: Ok, I got it, "contentType: 'application/json'" it helped and the second thing you told about.. I don't know how it happend :D

Answer (score 0):

Your url should be `api/images/post`.  The `RoutePrefix` is "api/images", so you're missing the name of the method.