# Getting null in spring-boot REST request param from HTML form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot

I've an HTML form where I'm getting 2 inputs, which is submitted to a spring boot `REST` api. But in this simple application, I'm still receiving `null` as request in backend api.

**Form**

```
<div>
    <label>alphaID</label>  
    <div>
        <input id="alphaID" name="alphaID" type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Domain Name</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="domain" name="domain" type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon submit, I'm calling ajax call, like:

```
function formSubmit() {
    $("#productForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var requestJson = createRequestJSON();
        var url = config.myurl;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type : "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(requestJson),
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ) {
                console.log("sucess: " + data);
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log( "error: " + errorThrown );
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The backend is a spring-boot application with REST call:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Map<String, List<String>> validate(@Valid MyDTO myDTO) {

    System.out.println(myDTO.getId());          // GETTING null
    System.out.println(myDTO.getDomain());      // GETTING null

}
```

**MyDTO.java**

```
public class MyDTO {
    @JsonProperty("alpha_id")
    private String alphaID;

    @JsonProperty("domain")
    private String domain;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Content-Type` to

```
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

Add `@RequestBody` annotation

```java
public Map<String, List<String>> validate(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO myDTO)
```

Make sure you are calling proper URL and sending proper `content-type` from your browser request too.

Comment: From browser then, I should send `application/json`, right?

Comment: I made the changes, I'm getting error: `Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]`

Comment: Refer this post to add `content-type` and `Accept` header in Ajax call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754767/cannot-set-content-type-to-application-json-in-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to see if your `requestJson` actually has the correct format in order for the `MyDTO` to consume it.

You also don't have to `Json.stringify` you data. When you do this, you basically just send an string to the backend. The backend does not know that it hast to parse this string to get a valid document. You either just send the JavaScript object directly in the data property or you change the API to expect a String and parse it in the function later.