# Getting data from other sites using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to to get data within divs from other websites. 
How can I do that using JavaScript?

Comment: You will want to use JSONP - see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197802/cross-site-ajax-using-jquery

Comment: Depends on how you want the data. Normally you may use AJAX to load data asynchronously api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @jungalist: JSONP is for getting JSON as a `script` so that you can communicate cross domain. It won't help with page content.

Comment: Any comments from the OP ? Or we should just shut down this topic ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to cross domain restrictions you can't access the html directly using AJAX.

You can however use `Yahoo YQL` to select the part(s) of a page you want and have that html returned within `jsonp` data.

Example returning list of questions on main page of stackoverflow

```
var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://stackoverflow.com/\' and xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]//h3//a\'&format=json&callback=?';


$.getJSON( url, function(data){
    $.each(data.query.results.a, function(){       
        $('body').append('<div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com'+this.href +'">'+this.content+'</a></div>')          
     })
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTUx5/

YQL docs: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/index.html

EDIT: This does not work any more.

Comment: http://tekniksel.net/api/get_recent_posts/?dev=1 how can I get "URL" and "title" from a given link by using JavaScript?

Comment: try this demo  to parse data from your API http://jsfiddle.net/45Na7/

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using your piece of code on my website, so first of all: Thanks! I was just hoping you could explain a couple of things regarding the code as I hate to use stuff I don't fully understand. In the 'var url' in the query, you use @id="question-mini-list". I looked in the html of stack, and there is nothing by that name, so why does that work? Second: In the 'each', data.query.results.a I don't see 'query' or 'results' used anywhere else, so how do you know to use those?. Last question: at the end of your 'url' why 'callback=?' ? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Great Great Great example

Comment: This does not work anymore

Comment: @DavidNathan no...YQL dropped this feature

Answer (score -1):

You will either have to [use the JSONP technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197802/cross-site-ajax-using-jquery), as jungalist suggested above; or get your AJAX method to talk to a local PHP script which uses cURL:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#result').load('path/to/script.php');
```

**PHP:**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);` - that looks pretty unrelated and will result in an E_NOTICE. You should remove that and the `fclose` call. `CURLOPT_HEADER` is false by default so that line can be omitted, too.

Comment: At least phrase your "constructive comments" in a way where your snarkiness is less obvious