# Get data from other page with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I want to get data from other page with js or jquery or ajax but not php. I just found a sample on stack overflow. ([here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537838/getting-data-from-other-sites-using-javascript)) But when I write these codes on my index.html file, it doesn't work. I don't understand reason. Here is my codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type=”text/javascript”>
       var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'https://stackoverflow.com/\' and xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]//h3//a\'&format=json&callback=?';


        $.getJSON( url, function(data){
            $.each(data.query.results.a, function(){       
                $('body').append('<div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com'+this.href +'">'+this.content+'</a></div>');    
             });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this locally? CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is not supported on localhost by most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

it works as it is...

```js
var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://stackoverflow.com/\' and xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]//h3//a\'&format=json&callback=?';


$.getJSON( url, function(data){
    $.each(data.query.results.a, function(){       
        $('body').append('<div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com'+this.href +'">'+this.content+'</a></div>');    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: what you see in jsfiddle mirrors the behaviour of a single .html file. I think your problem is not the code itself. can you link your production URL, if any?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. OP's questions are: how to get data from another page? why does my code not work? I didn't want to critique or ask clarifications, I actually wanted to answer him.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem these codes, thank for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url = 'deneme.html';
            $.get(url, function(response) {
                $('div#external').html($(response).find('#content>ul>li').html());
            });
        });
      </script>
    <style> body, html{padding: 0; margin:0;}</style>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="external" >

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```